# Django form - How to save data or get data without having to save it to database?

Tags: python-3.x, django

I've created a form with some fields for users to enter data, and a button to submit them and run some functions, then display the results on the same page (without having to store it to the database).

Now I would like to add a button (view/download as PDF) to have the page generated as a PDF file, so that the user can save the results.

But I'm having trouble retrieving the entered data, even they are still displaying on the page. They don't seem to be stored in the variables (or I don't know where to look).

I've read that if using modelForm I can call the .save function and save data to the database. But for this app I don't really need a database (it's more like an one-off calculations). So I would like to know if there's any way to:

1. Get the entered data directly while they are still on display (after submitting the form).
2. Generate a PDF directly from what's on the page (like the print function that most browsers have, but with some customization such as without the headings and navigation bars).

Is there a way to do this? I've been searching a lot and can't seem to be able to find an answer. I'm still very new to Django and programming in general so please forgive me if I'm asking silly questions. Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: You need to store somewhere the data in order to do some action. If you don t want to use a database maybe you can store temporary the data on the frontend using localstorage or maybe in django using session.

Comment: Thank you! I've used session and it worked for getting the variables. Still haven't figured out a good way for the PDF except creating another view though, but it's beenl working fine so far.